# Java development kit internal error 61003

Tags: java

I downloaded the 32 bit JDK from Orcale official website , then while installing , this error came out.

[image]

When I click OK , it completes the installing process .However , when installing Netbeans IDE , it doesn't find the JDK even when I choose the folder that I installed the JDK on , and I think it's because of this error.

Comment: Check https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2147853_1.html#:~:text='Error%20code%2061003'%20can%20be,of%20whether%20UAC%20is%20enabled.

Answer (score 8):

I get the same error when installing jdk-8u261-windows-i586.exe on Windows Server 2008 R2(x64). You must close the dialog of JDK first, then install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)，after the installation is successful, install JDK again, so that no error will be reported.
If the error is still reported, restart the Windows Server.

Comment: That worked for me. Didn't even need to restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurred with my installation when I tried to install JDK 8 32 bits.
In my case I solved this, installing JDK 7 32 bits and after that, I installed Netbeans 8.1 without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when installing java on an old laptop with 32bit Windows 7. I got the same error, and after installation finished an exception was popping up when trying to access java from the command line ("The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing").

In my case it was enough to run the Windows Update and proceed with all of the pending important updates (after that I could run java without issues, there was no need to reinstall it).

If that doesn't help, there's an article on the topic that could prove useful:
https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/06/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing/

Answer (score 0):

[Installing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html) the JDK + Netbeans version works correctly and does not get that error.